# Calling JS function automatically when text field is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor

I have Razor page, where I want to display weekday with translations in index table. I want this calculation to be done and displayed on client side with simple JS function.

Page:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Trainings) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p call_function?='getWeekday(@item.Since)'></p> <!-- I want weekday to be displayed here -->
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Since)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

JS function:

```
<script>
        function getWeekday(date) {
            var weekdays = ({
                et: ["Pühapäev", "Esmaspäev", "Teisipäev", "Kolmapäev", "Neljapäev", "Reede", "Laupäev"],
                en: ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
            });

            var d = new Date(date);
            var n = weekdays['et'][d.getDay()]; // currentCultureCode
            return n;
        }
</script>
```

Is there name or expression how this kind of method is named?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no element-level event raised when the element is created in the DOM.

Instead, you can create your HTML then run a function when the DOM has loaded. You can also store the date coming from the `item.Since` property in a `data` attribute on the element to make the code more extensible, something like this:

```js
function getWeekday(date) {
  var weekdays = ({
    et: ["Pühapäev", "Esmaspäev", "Teisipäev", "Kolmapäev", "Neljapäev", "Reede", "Laupäev"],
    en: ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]
  });

  var d = new Date(date);
  var n = weekdays['et'][d.getDay()]; // currentCultureCode
  return n;
}

[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('table p'), function(p) {
  var date = new Date(p.dataset.since);
  p.textContent = getWeekday(date);
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><p data-since="2017-11-28"></p></td>
    <td>2017-11-28</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p data-since="2017-11-29"></p></td>
    <td>2017-11-29</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Or in jQuery:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('table p').text(function() {
    var date = new Date($(this).data('since'));
    return getWeekday(date);
  });
});
```